# How to make multiplication table in console.log with Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know it's weird question, but I have to show multiplication table below in cosole.log form because its my manager's order.

```
|1 ｜2 ｜3 ｜4 ｜5 ｜6 ｜7 ｜8 ｜9 ｜  
|2 ｜4 ｜6 ｜8 ｜10｜12｜14｜16｜18｜  
|3 ｜6 ｜9 ｜12｜15｜18｜21｜24｜27｜  
..............
```

I already made the code of multiplication table, below.

but I don't have any idea to make above form in console.log.
Could someone teach me how to make multiplication table above?

```js
"use strict";
var i;
var j;
for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
        console.log(`${i}×${j}=${i * j}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried console.table?

Comment: `console.table(a.map(k=>b.map(c=>c*k)))` where a and b are an array integers from 1 to 9

Comment: Just think of it logically. The first row is the numbers 1 through 9 multiplied by the first number in the row. Since `console.log` logs a row at a time, you'll need to construct a row, log it, then construct the next. Or use `console.table` as the other comments mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

– **gorak** comment is correct: ( but you need only one array )

```
let a = Array.from({length:10},(_, i)=>i) 

console.table(a.map(k=>a.map(c=>c*k)))
```

> if you dislike the rows and columns at zero:

```
function mult(f) {     // object of named values from "1" to "9"
  for(let n=1;n<10;++n) {
    this[n.toString(10)] = f * n;
} }

let myTable = {}
for(let x=1;x<10;++x) myTable[x.toString(10)] = new mult(x)

console.table(myTable)
```

> or (ES6 last one)

```
const l_1_9 = Array.from({length:9},(_, i)=>++i)
  ,   multX = f =>l_1_9.reduce((t,x)=>{t[x.toString(10)]=x*f ;return t},{})
  ;
console.table(l_1_9.reduce((e,n)=>{e[n.toString(10)]=multX(n);return e},{}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it , but i chose to print it with `document.write()` :

```
const matrix: number[][] = new Array<number[]>(10);
for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array<number>(10);
}

    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
               document.write(matrix[i][j]+"| ");
        }
        document.write("<br>");
    }
```

Output :

```
1| 2| 3| 4| 5| 6| 7| 8| 9| 10|
2| 4| 6| 8| 10| 12| 14| 16| 18| 20|
3| 6| 9| 12| 15| 18| 21| 24| 27| 30|
4| 8| 12| 16| 20| 24| 28| 32| 36| 40|
5| 10| 15| 20| 25| 30| 35| 40| 45| 50|
6| 12| 18| 24| 30| 36| 42| 48| 54| 60|
7| 14| 21| 28| 35| 42| 49| 56| 63| 70|
8| 16| 24| 32| 40| 48| 56| 64| 72| 80|
9| 18| 27| 36| 45| 54| 63| 72| 81| 90|
10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70| 80| 90| 100|
```

Comment: While the numbers are written in the correct order, this does not yield a nice formatting that the OP is asking for. You should handle printing 2-digit numbers and 1-digit numbers with a different amount of spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much ! your code is really simple and useful!

Comment: Hello shmulvad ! This is not a design solution, I wanted to give it the multiplication algorithm. From here he can take it and come to whatever output he wants in whatever design he wants ...

Answer (score 0):

To not have line breaks caused by separate calls to `console.log` for each new number you need to dynamically build up a string. This solution accomplishes that while also formatting your string correctly by padding the number with spaces if the amount of digits in the number is smaller than the max amount of digits.

```js
function padWithSpaces(num, strLen) {
    return num + ' '.repeat(strLen - num.toString().length);
}

function multTable(rows, cols) {
    const maxNumDigits = (rows * cols).toString().length;
    let table = '';
    for (let y = 1; y <= rows; y++) {
        for (let x = 1; x <= cols; x++) {
            table += '|' + padWithSpaces(x * y, maxNumDigits);
        }
        table += '|\n';
    }
    table = table.substring(0, table.length - 1); // Remove final newline
    console.log(table);
}

multTable(3, 9);
multTable(6, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea that formatting idea!

Answer (score 0):

`console.table` is a very nice way to display this kind of information, here's a way to do it which gives you some reusable utility functions:

```js
const range = n => [...Array(n).keys()]

const times = a => b => a * b;
const plus = a => b => a + b;

const toRows = cs => rs => rs.map(r => cs.map(f => f(r)));

const columns = range(5).map(times);

const rows = range(5);

const table = toRows(columns)(rows);

console.table(table);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!